# How to use case, when, in with an update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The first case will compile in the query, but when I add the second case the error below appears "Incorrect syntax near 'program'". How do I use a list for the IN clause in the update. 2008r

```
       academic_session =  CASE PC.KEY5 
                                WHEN 'AGS' THEN 'AGS' 
                                WHEN 'TRD' THEN 'Traditional'
                           END,
       program = CASE PC.KEY3
            WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('FF-AGS', 'FF-TRD', 'TR-AGS', 'CH-TRD', 'CO-TRD', 'RE-TRD', 'TR-TRD', 'WDVW') THEN 'Undergraduate'
            WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'CROSS' THEN 'CROSS'
            WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'GR-AGS' THEN 'Graduate'
            WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('ND-AGS', 'ND-TRD') THEN 'Non Degree Seeking'
        END program,
```

Incorrect syntax near 'program'.

Posted each condition on a separate row and it compiles.

```
       program = CASE PC.KEY3
            --WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('FF-AGS', 'FF-TRD', 'TR-AGS', 'CH-TRD', 'CO-TRD', 'RE-TRD', 'TR-TRD', 'WDVW') THEN 'Undergraduate' --"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'"
            WHEN 'FF-AGS' THEN 'Undergraduate'
            WHEN 'FF-TRD' THEN 'Undergraduate'
            WHEN 'TR-AGS' THEN 'Undergraduate'
            WHEN 'CH-TRD' THEN 'Undergraduate'           
            WHEN 'CO-TRD' THEN 'Undergraduate'               
            WHEN 'RE-TRD' THEN 'Undergraduate'           
            WHEN 'TR-TRD' THEN 'Undergraduate'           
            WHEN 'WDVW' THEN 'Undergraduate'                 
            WHEN 'CROSS' THEN 'CROSS'
            WHEN 'GR-AGS' THEN 'Graduate'
            WHEN 'ND-AGS' THEN 'Non Degree Seeking'
            WHEN 'ND-TRD' THEN 'Non Degree Seeking'
        END,
```

Comment: Remove `program` after the `end`.  It is not syntactically correct in an `update` query.

Comment: Thanks, when I remove program, the message appears "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'"      program = CASE PC.KEY3
    WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('FF-AGS', 'FF-TRD', 'TR-AGS', 'CH-TRD', 'CO-TRD', 'RE-TRD', 'TR-TRD', 'WDVW') THEN 'Undergraduate'
    WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'CROSS' THEN 'CROSS'
    WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'GR-AGS' THEN 'Graduate'
    WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('ND-AGS', 'ND-TRD') THEN 'Non Degree Seeking'
   END,

Comment: The fact that you have a 3000 code lines stored procedure means you are doing something wrong on the design level. All these hard coded `case...when` should probably be removed and the relationship between the values should be encapsulated in tables, for one thing.

Comment: Just a thought. Instead of hard-coding each value codes and returning the descriptive text, it is highly recommended if you add a table that will hold those CODES and DESCRIPTIONS. From there, you can have it JOIN in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Elmer This is exactly what I suggested 56 minutes ago...

Comment: @Zohar, well then that's great.

Comment: I have that method using tables but the users don't want to update the tables, so we have another method using the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
academic_session =  CASE PC.KEY5 
                                WHEN 'AGS' THEN 'AGS' 
                                WHEN 'TRD' THEN 'Traditional'
                                ELSE NULL
                           END,
 program = CASE WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('FF-AGS', 'FF-TRD', 'TR-AGS', 'CH-TRD', 'CO-TRD', 'RE-TRD', 'TR-TRD', 'WDVW') THEN 'Undergraduate'
           CASE WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'CROSS' THEN 'CROSS'
           CASE WHEN PC.KEY3 = 'GR-AGS' THEN 'Graduate'
           CASE WHEN PC.KEY3 IN ('ND-AGS', 'ND-TRD') THEN 'Non Degree Seeking'
        ELSE NULL
        END ,
```

Comment: Thanks, when I remove program, the message appears "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'"

Comment: @ERPISE try again

Comment: the error is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'." this is 2008r, which version do you have?

Comment: can you post the full script. thanks

Comment: It's 3000 lines, I don't know if it will fit. If I post each condition on a separate row it will compile without errors.

Comment: post the case statement where there is an error.. i need to see the script that bums out

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2jHNaXjf

Comment: @erpise i don't think you are copying the solution correctly. check my solution and apply to your query

Comment: I repasted it, and get the error  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.", line on pastebin 2772

Comment: @maSTAShuFu You need to add closing `END` to each `CASE` !

Comment: @MichałTurczyn  nope.... multiple case when if you a variety of conditions otherwise you one case and multiple when